# Office 365 IMAP Authentication fail for PLAIN access with OPENSSL

Tags: authentication, outlook, openssl, office365, imap

I'm trying to test and Office 365 (with Outlook) account for remote access via IMAP.  Despite the large amount of posts regarding this issue, i was not able to find something that make my test work, so i'm asking again.
This is the scenario : I have an outlook/office365 account, with IMAP enabled by the admin.

[image]

From a local server i'm using the next command from openssl to connect to the IMAP server:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect outlook.office365.com:993 -quiet
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert Cloud Services CA-1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, CN = outlook.com
verify return:1
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UwBDADEAUABSADgAMABDAEEAMAAwADUAOAAuAGwAYQBtAHAAcgBkADgAMAAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
```

Apparently i'm connected to the IMAP server, so now i try to authenticate.
First i get the list of AUTH methods that the server accepts.

```
02 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
02 OK CAPABILITY completed
```

So, i try to authenticate using PLAIN.  As far as i understand i need to put the credentials in base64 format, so i use the command "base64" from my linux server in order to get.
So, if my username is "user@mydomain.com" and my password is "mysecretpassword" i use this:

```
echo -en "\0user@mydomain.com\0mysecretpassword" | openssl base64
```

I get

```
AHVzZXJAbXlkb21haW4uY29tAG15c2VjcmV0cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Then in the connection i use :

```
01 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
+
AHVzZXJAbXlkb21haW4uY29tAG15c2VjcmV0cGFzc3dvcmQ=
01 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

No matter what i try i always get "AUTHENTICATE failed".
Maybe i'm not doing something wrong?.  Do i need to set up something else in the office365 server? Is correct to asume if the server answer with AUTH=PLAIN as capability i can use this method to authenticate?.
On other hand I'm 100% sure about my user and password, i can connec to to the SMTP (smpt.office365.com) server with this credentials without any problem.
I have tried without luck this credentials:

```
"\0user@mydomain.com\0mysecretpassword"
"\000user@mydomain.com\000mysecretpassword"
"\0user@mydomain.com\0user@mydomain.com\0mysecretpassword"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The last one should not start with a NUL.  The format is `authorization-id NUL authentication-id NUL password`, with the authorization-ID being optional; Only if you omit it would your data start with a \0. so `user NUL user NUL pw` is acceptable.

Comment: That being said, if it's Office 365, plain text authentication of any kind is being deprecated and may actually not be enabled on your server, despite what the capabilities may say.  You can always try `01 LOGIN user PW` which is equivalent to AUTHENTICATE, but without the base64 encoding.

Comment: Hi @Max .  Thanks for the clarification.  I didn't know that PLAIN AUTH was deprecated.  That answer a lot of questions.  Now... if capabilities don't mention AUTH=LOGIN, only AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2, i think the only option i have is to use XOAUTH2?.  I was trying since he beggining with `01 LOGIN user@mydomain.com mysecretpassword` and i'm getting the same answer: `01 NO LOGIN failed`

Comment: LOGIN is not the same as AUTH=LOGIN; in a standard server, LOGIN is always available unless the LOGINDISABLED ‘capability’ is present.  But yes, MS is disabling any kind of plain text authentication, which is drawing quite a lot of attention, and making things much more difficult for developers.

Comment: OAuth2 is indeed the desired transition, but it requires a lot of set up to get going.

Comment: Thanks again.  Just to get this thing clear , the command LOGIN is consider as a "plain text authentication"?.  Because, AUTH=PLAIN es very clear ....

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

Yes, anything that involves the user’s actual password.

Comment: well... thank you Max!.

Comment: A weird thing happen today.  Using an account, from another office365 user, we try to connect using the above command "LOGIN" and works OK.   Maybe the LOGIN or "AUTH PLAIN" is not the issue?.  Maybe something in the account configuration?

Comment: I have seen something similar happen... sometime in the last week or two (I am not sure exactly when) POP and IMAP access by Evolution (3.38.3; Debian 11) to Office365 Outlook mailboxes has stopped working.  IMAP claims both "AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2" supported (and Evolution certainly doesn't seem to know anything about OAuth) but then the login fails.

Answer (score 5):

I have finally made some tests and thanks to @Max who pointed my in the right direction i was able to make this thing work.  I have contacted MS support and I was able to first check the IMAP status of my Office365 account.
I followed the steps here (https://www.kraftkennedy.com/how-to-temporarily-re-enable-basic-authentication-in-exchange-online/) in order to check the status of my IMAP service, and it was with Basic Auth disabled..., so with the admin account i was able to enable it using a little box.
[image]
Then i was succesfully able to login using "Basic Auth"..with
01 AUTHETICATE PLAIN Ahfu4sdjkdsu9d9d9wee4
01 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.

And with
01 LOGIN user pass
01 OK LOGIN completed.

So, as @Max mention, Microsoft is disabling "Basic Auth" for good, but you can enable it again.
Hope this could be useful for all.

Regards,